# What is this, and why is it happening?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

So I have been working on my final project for the semester for my Computer Systems class, and we have been tasked to make a game using Flash and ActionScript 3.0. I've pretty much completed everything but I have come across an extremely strange occurrence of Flash CS6 being silly. I am moving a MovieClip up and down depending on a selected index, however, the image leaves 'residue of it's footprints' behind and also moves. I have tried hard to look for an answer as to why this is happening, but I don't know what it's called, or how to appropriately explain it - I'm coming from an area where one must program graphics, not just simply, drag and drop.

Below are pictures as to what I've come across, but first the code I'm using:

```
function updateThemeScreen():void {
    button_selection.y += (selectedPositions[selectedTheme] - button_selection.y) / 2;
}
function attemptThemeChange(mxP:Number, myP:Number):void {
    if(objectContains(theme_darkness, mxP, myP)) {
        selectedTheme = 0;
    } else if(objectContains(theme_halloween, mxP, myP)) {
        selectedTheme = 1;
    }
}
```

[image: Image One - Normal and expected]
[image: Image Two - Normal and expected]
[image: Image Three - Not expected]

As you can see in the final image, it has copied half of itself and left it at the last button, which is strange, and shouldn't happen...

Link to the SWF zipped up with the required AS3 classes: [Dude, RUN](https://mega.co.nz/#!Np0WTQKJ!PvnVWVOE7SymeBJdyryfpfl_j_TuQzNBULro7YPyaLc)

Comment: Did you try playing / reproducing problem in browser players or Just CS6 player?

Comment: Just the CS6 player.

Comment: Try playing your swf in variety of browsers, if there is no such glitch you can simply ignore the problem of editting environment, right?

Comment: I just tried playing it in a browser, and the problem still persists. I have no idea what this problem is called...

Comment: Could you share this swf so I can have a closer Look on it?

Comment: @Anonymous, Link added to the end of the original post.

Comment: I've tried it on firefox, windows 7 x64, Flash Player 11,8,800,168 - the problem doesn't occur. I'm almost sure it is related to flash player plugin version or your graphics card drivers. Can't help, sorry.

Comment: I've been thinking that it's because my computer has started running out of resources. I only have 2G ram. And I'm using the motherboards graphics card. Nonetheless, it's a strange problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that I have magically fixed this problem by hiding the buttons and showing them all in one frame. I don't know what this problem is or why it does it, but to fix it, you just need to hide and show the affected components - yes, **in one frame:**

```
function hideShow(object:MovieClip):void {
  object.visible = false;
  object.visible = true;
}
```